# Return the longest consecutive sequence of a value in specific column

Tags: cte, window-functions, postgresql-12

I am using PostgreSQL 12.0 and trying to get the longest sequence of continuous rows for a specific column and value.

The table is called team2 and contains a team's results which looks like:

`match_id (pk), team_name (varchar), opposition (varchar), match_result (varchar)`

My query is trying to find the longest sequence of 'Win' in match_result. There are 23 Wins in total and using the eye the longest sequence should return 5. However 23 is returned. How can I alter my query to select only the longest sequence?

```
WITH ConsecutiveSequences AS (
  SELECT
    match_result,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY match_id) AS grp
  FROM team2
  WHERE match_result = 'Win'
),
GroupedSequences AS (
  SELECT
    match_result,
    COUNT(*) AS consecutive_count
  FROM ConsecutiveSequences
  GROUP BY match_result, grp
)
SELECT
  COALESCE(MAX(consecutive_count), 0) AS longest_consecutive_sequence
FROM GroupedSequences;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Longest sequence of continuous rows" implies an order, which in this case is match_id.

Let's make a generic example:

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE matches (
    match_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    crit     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    result   INTEGER NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO matches SELECT n,random()*100,random()*0.8 FROM generate_series(1,1000) n;
```

- "result" may be 0 or 1 for win or loss.
- "crit" is a generic criteria that could be the team being considered (or anything else, for the sake of example).

So let's get the length of the longest sequence of contiguous rows, in match_id order, having the same result and crit. Detecting a solid sequence of identical values means comparing each row with the previous one, which means the window function LAG() is required.

```
SELECT  crit, match_id, result, 
        lag(crit,1)   OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id) as last_result,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id) as rownum
FROM matches;
 crit | match_id | result | last_result | rownum
------+----------+--------+-------------+--------
    0 |       43 |      0 |        Null |      1
    0 |       71 |      0 |           0 |      2
    0 |      393 |      0 |           0 |      3
    0 |      410 |      0 |           0 |      4
    0 |      597 |      0 |           0 |      5
    0 |      696 |      1 |           0 |      6
    0 |      728 |      0 |           0 |      7
    0 |      783 |      0 |           0 |      8
    0 |      824 |      1 |           0 |      9
    1 |      512 |      1 |        Null |      1
    1 |      552 |      1 |           1 |      2
    1 |      610 |      1 |           1 |      3
    1 |      633 |      0 |           1 |      4
    1 |      823 |      1 |           1 |      5
    1 |      892 |      0 |           1 |      6
    1 |      980 |      1 |           1 |      7
    2 |        3 |      1 |        Null |      1
 ...
```

We can't use match_result in WHERE like you did in your question, because that would eliminate the rows with the wrong values... and we need to keep these rows as they act as a delimiter between runs of identical result values. In your query, you keep only the wins, so there are no lost matches to set the bounds around a sequence of wins. Only a single sequence of wins remains. Thus you get the count of wins in the table, as you noticed, which is not what you want.

So we need to locate the beginning and end of a sequence of rows having the same crit and result, by comparing the current and previous rows. One important thing to remember is LAG() returns NULL for the first row in the partition, so there needs to be a special case for the first row.

```
SELECT  crit, match_id, result, 
        (   (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id)) = 1
         OR result != lag(result,1) OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id)
        ) AS start_run
FROM matches;
 crit | match_id | result | start_run
------+----------+--------+---------
    0 |       43 |      0 | t
    0 |       71 |      0 | f
    0 |      393 |      0 | f
    0 |      410 |      0 | f
    0 |      597 |      0 | f
    0 |      696 |      1 | t
    0 |      728 |      0 | t
    0 |      783 |      0 | f
    0 |      824 |      1 | t
    1 |      512 |      1 | t
    1 |      552 |      1 | f
    1 |      610 |      1 | f
    1 |      633 |      0 | t
...
```

So now we have new_run=true at the beginning of a new sequence. In order to count the rows in a sequence, we either need to give each sequence an id and use count() and group by, or get row_number() for the first and last row of the sequence and substract them.

To detect the last row of a sequence, we need to compare the current row with the next one, by using lead() instead of lag(). However lead() will be NULL if this is the last row in the partition. In the previous case we detected the first row in the partition with row_number()=1 but this is not possible for the last row as its row_number() is not known. So we'll use lead() on a non-nullable column like match_id instead. "result" could also ne used if it is not nullable.

```
SELECT  crit, match_id, result, 
    CASE WHEN 
        (   (lag(match_id,1) OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id)) IS NULL
         OR result != lag(result,1) OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id))
        THEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id) ELSE NULL END
        AS start_run,
    CASE WHEN (   (lead(match_id,1) OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id)) IS NULL
         OR result != lead(result,1) OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id))
        THEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id) ELSE NULL END
        AS end_run
FROM matches;
 crit | match_id | result | start_run | end_run
------+----------+--------+-----------+---------
    0 |       43 |      0 |         1 |    Null
    0 |       71 |      0 |      Null |    Null
    0 |      393 |      0 |      Null |    Null
    0 |      410 |      0 |      Null |    Null
    0 |      597 |      0 |      Null |       5
    0 |      696 |      1 |         6 |       6
    0 |      728 |      0 |         7 |    Null
    0 |      783 |      0 |      Null |       8
    0 |      824 |      1 |         9 |       9
    1 |      512 |      1 |         1 |    Null
    1 |      552 |      1 |      Null |    Null
    1 |      610 |      1 |      Null |       3
    1 |      633 |      0 |         4 |       4
    1 |      823 |      1 |         5 |       5
    1 |      892 |      0 |         6 |       6
    1 |      980 |      1 |         7 |       7
    2 |        3 |      1 |         1 |    Null
    2 |      127 |      1 |      Null |    Null
    2 |      231 |      1 |      Null |       3
```

After checking that the results are correct (especially on boundaries) we can remove the rows with both start_run and end_run set to NULL and keep only the rows that indicate the start and end of a run, then get its length. The bit with COALESCE is due to runs having thart_run in the same or previous row if length is 1 or greater.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT crit, result,
        CASE 
            WHEN end_run IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 1+end_run-COALESCE( start_run, LAG(start_run,1) OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id))
            ELSE NULL END
            AS run_length
        FROM (
        SELECT  crit, match_id, result, 
            CASE WHEN 
                (   (lag(match_id,1) OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id)) IS NULL
                 OR result != lag(result,1) OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id))
                THEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id) ELSE NULL END
                AS start_run,
            CASE WHEN (   (lead(match_id,1) OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id)) IS NULL
                 OR result != lead(result,1) OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id))
                THEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY crit ORDER BY match_id) ELSE NULL END
                AS end_run
        FROM matches) a
        WHERE start_run IS NOT NULL or end_run IS NOT NULL
    ) b WHERE run_length IS NOT NULL;

 crit | result | run_length
------+--------+------------
    0 |      0 |          5
    0 |      1 |          1
    0 |      0 |          2
    0 |      1 |          1
    1 |      1 |          3
    1 |      0 |          1
    1 |      1 |          1
    1 |      0 |          1
```

To get the longest run, you can replace the first and last lines of the previous query with

```
SELECT crit, result, max(run_length) FROM (
...rest of the query...
) b WHERE run_length IS NOT NULL GROUP BY crit, result;
```